# Spring ViewResolver Problem

Tags: java, spring-mvc

My application was running succestfully until I add a `org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver` in it. It gives the error:

> javax.servlet.ServletException: Could not resolve view with name '/jsp/cusbilman/main/billportmain.jsp' in servlet with name 'cusbilman'

I think it broke the default redirection method:

Any ideas?

---

**Update**

The code:

```
<bean id="htmlViewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/cusbilman/resources/static/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".html"/>
        <property name="viewNames">
            <list>
                <value>html1</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Old bean definition:

```
<bean id="billingPortalMainController" class="com.tt.cusman.cusbilman.main.view.BillingPortalMainController" >
<property name="commandName"><value>dummy</value></property>            
<property name="commandClass"><value>com.tt.cusman.cusbilman.main.view.command.DummyObject</value></property>   
<property name="sessionForm"><value>false</value></property>
<property name="formView"><value>/jsp/cusbilman/main/billportmain.jsp</value></property>
<property name="successView"><value>/jsp/cusbilman/main/billportmain.jsp</value></property>
<property name="searchView"><value>/../cusinfman/search/search.html</value></property>
<property name="postPaidHome"><value>/cusbilman/cusbilman/invoices.html?page=new</value></property>
<property name="prePaidHome"><value>/cusbilman/cusbilman/prepaid/main.html?page=new</value></property>
<property name="emptyForm"><value>/cusbilman/jsp/cusbilman/main/emptyForm.jsp</value></property>
<property name="cusbilmanMainQdbDao" ref="cusbilmanMainQdbDao" />
```

Thanks for the reply

Comment: post relevant configuration & code

Answer (score 1):

The view resolver will combine it's own `prefix` and `suffix` properties with the name you return from your controller.

In this case, it will use

```
"/cusbilman/resources/static/" + "/jsp/cusbilman/main/billportmain.jsp" + ".html"
```

and will therefore try and look for a file inside the webapp base directory named

```
/cusbilman/resources/static//jsp/cusbilman/main/billportmain.jsp.html
```

which looks seriously wrong to me.

You need to sort out your view resolver prefix and JSP paths.

Comment: No, it does not handle this way, because if it handle it from your way, the error message would give it with that way: billportmain.jsp.html. I want the new viewhandler to be focused on the url's like this: /cusbilman/resources/static/html1

Comment: @Ali: No, that's not true. Your "view name" is still `/jsp/cusbilman/main/billportmain.jsp`, and that's what the error message is referring to. I'm telling you what the problem with your setup is. If you choose not to believe it, fair enough.

Comment: Do not be so offensive, it was just an idea. The thing that I want to do is, to call an html page witout passing on a controller. I could do it with a simple html href but, it can create security problems and I do not want to touch the app server properties etc.